# unable to redirect from modal via routerLink

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I created a modal window using MatDialogRef. This modal is opened from offer form on button click (/offers/:id). Inside my modal window there are 2 buttons:

[image]

I want following behavior: when I click on 'Edit prices' I need to be redirected to prices /offers/:id/prices

I tried to achieve that by following code:

```
<a mat-button [routerLink]="['prices']" target="_blank" mat-stroked-button>Edit prices</a>
```

But currently it just opens new tab with the same url /offers/:id. Why just it doesn't append 'prices' to current url? How can I achieve desired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<a mat-button [routerLink]="['/prices']" target="_blank" mat-stroked-button>Edit prices</a>
```

Maybe it is because you omitted the "/"
or
try this
Edit prices

Comment: nope, I tried this, but it redirects me to 'localhost/prices' instead of 'localhost/offers/:id/prices'